# How to run a list of vim commands in the current buffer from an external file

Tags: vim, data-cleaning

I frequently use Vim to parse and clean up data exported from other sources. Often, I find myself running a sequence of substitute commands. I'd like to save those commands to some kind of script file, then run it on the current buffer.

An example of the commands found in sample script could be:

```
:%s/pattern1/pattern2/g
:%s/pattern3/pattern4/g
:v/pattern5/d
... etc
```

If the script were in the same directory as the current buffer file (or maybe in the .vim folder), how could I load and run these commands as if I were typing them in manually?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Vim window open and want to execute VimL on a buffer, you can do:

```
:source /path/to/vim/file/name.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your commands in `script.vim`:

   ```
   :%s/pattern1/pattern2/g
   :%s/pattern3/pattern4/g
   :v/pattern5/d
   ```
2. Use it like this:

   ```
   $ vim filetocleanup -s script.vim
   ```

See `:help -s`.